# Trying to pass name as parameter in dropdown form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form where I am dynamically passing an id already of an array of populated events. I need to now pass a name so the name can later be grabbed to store in the database.

This is not working passing the name through $attributes. Because when I inspect the div element where the value appears after selected, it just shows the id of the event from the elements table.

```
 <?php
            if($user_events){
                //print_r($user_events);
            ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">
                        <p></p>

                      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
                      <?php 
                        //$user_events = '';
                        //print_r($user_events);
                        $ar=array();
                        foreach($user_events as $events) {
                            $ar[$events['id']] = $events['title'];
                            }
                      //endforeach;
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        $attributes = 'input type = “hidden” name="posted_event[]"';
                         //$attributes='';
                         echo form_dropdown('myselect', $ar, '',$attributes);    

                        ?> 

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              </div>
              <?php    
              }
              ?>
              <button id="grab1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                      <hr/>
            </div>
```

Basically when I inspect the element I need to see this

```
<input type = “hidden” name = “posted_event[]">
```

Updated:

```
$attributes = '<input type = "hidden" name="posted_event[]">';
```

Comment: This `“hidden”` contains curly quotes. If it's part of your actual code, change them to regular quotes `"hidden"`. That alone will cause havoc.

Comment: Plus, not entirely sure as to why this `input type = “hidden” name="posted_event[]"` seems to be missing opening `<` and closing `>` symbols. As in `<input type = "hidden" name="posted_event[]">`

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is all I am getting in inspect element <li data-value="22">Mon 541</li>

Comment: You dont need the name i.e. `$events['title']`. As you have the `id` you can fetch the name from the table that contains id and title anytime you want it in the script that processes the data from the form. Or better still you store the `id` only in other tables and then if you want the `title` you join the relevant tables to get it, if and when you need it.

Comment: If i understand this correctly, you want to grab the value of select (probably onChange) and pass it to your hidden input ?

Comment: I dont understand why you need type='hidden'? also u already have 'myselect' as name. Also you dont need < and > in attributes in fom_dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You are using form_dropdown which is for a drop down, you need to use form_input() if you want to produce what you want.

```
    $data = array(
                  'type'        => 'hidden',
                  'name'          => 'postedevent[]',
                );

echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: But then I will have not dropdown to select vlaues from.I am passing the selected option to a div by jquery. I need the selected option to have a name that can be passed to db when I right click on it and inspect element.

Comment: Please give example of how you want the dropdown html to look? Its confusing. Also "input" cannot be mixed with dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to implement a dropdown? You can use `<select> <option></option> </select>` ryt?. Did you ever try this method?

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">

<select id="yourid" name='name'>
     <?php 
                        //$user_events = '';
                        //print_r($user_events);
                        $ar=array();
                        foreach($user_events as $events) {

        ?>
<option value='<?php echo $events['id']; ?>'> <?php echo $events['title']; ?></option>

<?php
}
                      //endforeach;
                        ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I found out what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a couple hours I now have the exact answer.
I was looking to pass the hidden id and name through the form_dropdown through a parameter. This was not working so I had to append the html to an id in the javascript like so:

Markup

```
            <?php
            if($user_promos){
                print_r($user_promos);
            ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div id="myselect2" class="col-md-12">
                        <p></p>

                      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">
                      <?php 
                        //$user_events = '';
                        //print_r($user_events);
                        $ar=array();
                        foreach($user_events as $events) {
                            $ar[$events['id']] = $events['title'];
                            }
                      //endforeach;
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        $attributes = '';
                         //$attributes='';
                         echo form_dropdown('myselect', $ar, '',$attributes);    

                        ?> 

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              </div>
              <?php    
              }
              ?>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $("#event").hide();
  $("#events").hide();
  $("#myselect select").change(function() {
    var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
    if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
      $('<li />', {
        'data-value': $selected.val(),
         id:'a'+$selected.val(),
         text: $selected.text()
      }).appendTo('#events');
      $selected.addClass('added');
      $("#a"+$selected.val()).append('<input type="hidden" name="posted_event[]" value="'+$selected.text()+'">');
    }

    $("#event").show();
    $("#events").show();

  });
});
```

Output:

```
<li data-value="26" id="a26">Event title<input type="hidden" name="posted_event[]" value="Event title"></li>
```